# Check current page url contents in liferay velocity template

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I am trying to find out current page url contents and parameters in liferay Velocity(vm)file.
I am able to get current page url by this way.

I have tried to decode url

```
 http://localhost:8080/web/guest/sign-in?p_p_id=45&p_p_lifecycle=0&_58_redirect=‌​%2Fgroup%2Femployee%2FmainForm%3FempName%3DABC
```

using following way

```
#set($absoluteUrl= $theme_display.getURLCurrent())
#set ($test=$httpUtil.decodeURL($absoluteUrl))
```

Now I am getting url as

```
/web/guest/sign-in?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&_58_redirect=/group/employee/mainForm?empName=ABC
```

Now I am trying to get value of `empName` by this way.

```
#set($empName= $request.getParameter("empName"))
```

But still unable to get anything? What I am missing? how can I get value of this parameter now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check substrings in velocity by this:

```
#set ($url = $themeDisplay.getURLCurrent())

#if($url.contains("&empName=ABC"))
The url contains the string <b>&empName=ABC<b>
#else
The url does not contain the string <b>&empName=ABC</b>
#end
```

If you want to check for request parameter existance prior to check its content:

```
#set($empName = $request.getParameter("empName"))

#if (!$empName) 
<h1>Parameter not found</h1>
#else
<h1>Parameter found: $empName</h1>
#end`
```

Tested in Liferay 6.1.1 ce ga2

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It works, but how can I check my `&empName` value as it will be dynamic. Means first we will check whether url contains `&empName` & if answer is yes we will need value of `&empName` , how can achieve it?

Comment: and what if url contain parameter in format like empName%3DABC,then how we can get value of empName?

Comment: Actually that is not a regular http request format. Can you post the whole url as example?

Comment: my http url is `http://localhost:8080/group/employee/mainForm?empName=ABC` and when I paste that url in browser it changes as `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/sign-in?p_p_id=45&p_p_lifecycle=0&_58_redirect=%2Fgroup%2Femployee%2FmainForm%3FempName%3DABC` so how can check value of empName ?

Comment: The url is rewritten by the server, and the only parameters I see are: 
p_p_id 
p_p_lifecycle
_58_redirect

Comment: You may want to check the last one that contains what seems to me an URL encoded string.
But what I suppose is that the original url is rewritten because you have to login to the system, then the system itself will redirect to the original url.

Comment: @yes you are right but how can I check that encoded string value?

Comment: I have decoded `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/sign-in?p_p_id=45&p_p_lifecycle=0&_58_redirect=‌​%2Fgroup%2Femployee%2FmainForm%3FempName%3DABC ` please see my updated question

Comment: @ Alessandro Alessandra finally it worked ,I have added my answer also.   Thnaks  Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

If url is like in this way:

```
 http://localhost:8080/web/guest/sign-in?p_p_id=45&p_p_lifecycle=0&_58_redirect=‌​%2Fgroup%2Femployee%2FmainForm%3FempName%3DABC
```

Now we can decode this url as :

```
#set($url= $theme_display.getURLCurrent())
#set ($decodedUrl=$httpUtil.decodeURL($url))
```

So  I am getting url as

```
/web/guest/sign-in?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&_58_redirect=/group/employee/mainForm?empName=ABC
```

Now we can get value of empName by this way:

```
#set($empName=$decodedUrl.split("empName=").get(1))
```

So we will get value of $empName=ABC

Answer (score 0):

$themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getPathFriendlyURL($themeDisplay.getLayout().isPrivateLayout(),$themeDisplay)+$layout.getGroup().friendlyURL

this will check if the page is private layout and will display /[web|group]/[site-name]/

Answer (score 0):

Compare current URL:

```
if($portal.getCurrentURL($request) == "/home")
```

or

```
if($portal.getCurrentURL($request).indexOf("/demo-demo")>=0)
```

This returns all the URLs starting with 'demo-demo';